# Wordpress install on add-on site redirecting to main site

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

My main website is:

http://sandybeachit.co.uk

I have a wordpress site setup at my addon-domain:

[http://imadeitviral.com][1]

The wordpress site is in:

```
/hosting/imadeitviral
```

The above address can be found here on the primary site under sandybeachit.co.uk/hosting/imadeitviral/

I have got the site url and home set to "http:// imadeitviral.com" (without the space between "http:// and madeitviral.com"

But when you go imadeitviral.com the site attempts to load my primary site at sandybeachit.co.uk except the site does not load correctly, you can try it and your see what i mean.

If i set the wordpress site url and home to pointing to "sandybeachit.co.uk/hosting/imadeitviral" the site will load fine, so i know i have got something wrong, but i can not figure out what.

I have tried removing the .htaccess file in my main domain and editing it so i an sure its not that is the problem as well as the .htaccess file in the wordpress folder.

I did the install via Site Software Softaculous Apps Installer

Can i get some pointers as to what i have done wrong or missed ?

Thanks

HTACCESS FILE IN WORDPRESS DIRECTORY:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /hosting/imadeitviral/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /hosting/imadeitviral/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

HTACCESS FILE IN MAIN DIRECTORY:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?imadeitviral\.com
    RewriteRule .* - [L]


RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*)/$ /$1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule .*[^/]$ /$0/ [L,R=301]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

#RULES ADDED AFTER 14TH JANUARY 2017

# Set Timezone
<IfModule !fcgid_module>
php_value date.timezone "Europe/London"
</IfModule>

# Disable directory browsing
Options All -Indexes


### Security - Disable HTTP Track and Trace
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(TRACE|TRACK)
RewriteRule .* - [F]

# STRONG HTACCESS PROTECTION
<Files ~ "^.*\.([Hh][Tt][Aa])">
 order allow,deny
 deny from all
 satisfy all
</Files>

#DENY ACCESS - START
<FilesMatch "config.php|\.tpl$">
 Order allow,deny
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
#DENY ACCESS - END

# One year for image files
<filesMatch ".(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public"
</filesMatch>
# One month for css and js
<filesMatch ".(css|js)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2628000, public"
</filesMatch>

<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)(\.gz)?$">
Header set Expires "Thu, 15 Apr 2012 20:00:00 GMT"
Header unset ETag
FileETag None
</FilesMatch>


# BEGIN EXPIRES
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 10 days"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType text/plain "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType application/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>
# END EXPIRES

# GZIP BEGIN - COMPRESS - .CSS .JS .HTML .XHTML .PHP .TXT
#Gzip
<ifmodule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/text text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/x- javascript application/javascript
</ifmodule>
#End Gzip

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    #The following line is enough for .js and .css
    AddOutputFilter DEFLATE js css

    #The following line also enables compression by file content type, for the following list of Content-Type:s
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml application/xml

    #The following lines are to avoid bugs with some browsers
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
    BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html 
</IfModule>

<ifModule mod_headers.c>
  Header unset Vary
  Header set Vary "Accept-Encoding, X-HTTP-Method-Override, X-Forwarded-For, Remote-Address, X-Real-IP, X-Forwarded-Proto, X-Forwarded-Host, X-Forwarded-Port, X-Forwarded-Server"
</ifModule>
```

After a little more testing:

What i am finding is if i goto:

imadeitviral.com/

The site loads

As soon as i go into:

imadeitviral.com/wp-admin

after a short while the site times out to a 404 with the message:

"Not Found

The requested URL /wp-admin/plugins.php was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request."